# x509 certificate subject alternative name

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate

When using the x509 certificate in c++ obtained using the function `SSL_get_peer_certificate`, which function should be used to handle the `subject alternative name` field of the certificate? Some certificates dont have multiple CN's but have multiple `subject alternative name`. How should that be handled?

I was able to get the x509_EXTENSIONS struture.

```
typedef struct X509_extension_st
    {
    ASN1_OBJECT *object;
    ASN1_BOOLEAN critical;
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING *value;
    } X509_EXTENSION;
```

What is the difference between the `object` and the `value` pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in some of recent versions of OpenSSL, the `X509_st` (of which type the peer cert is) contains a field `STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *altname`. If you are able to access it, it should solve your problem.